# How to get load capacitances from an FPGA design for third-party dynamic power analysis?

Tags: power, fpga, vivado

I would like to perform dynamic power analysis of an FPGA design outside the design tool environment. For this, I need the equivalent load capacitance of every net in the design. How can I get the necessary load capacitance values?

I am using a Xilinx Artix-7 100t FPGA and Vivado ML v2022.2. The answer does not have to be restricted to this model and design tool.

Comment: Is the [Xilinx Power Estimator (XPE)](https://www.xilinx.com/products/technology/power/xpe.html) spreadsheet based tool any use? While it might not get the the fidelity of answer you need, it is outside of the Vivado tool.

Comment: I checked [XPE documentation](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documents/sw_manuals/xilinx2022_2/ug440-xilinx-power-estimator.pdf), which doesn't show any way to extract existing loads in a design.